# How to manage tall menus (lists of languages)?

Tags: visual-c++, menu, mfc

My application supports over 30 languages:

[image]

What is the right way to manage the situation where the menu is too tall for the screen? I will slowly get extra languages added and I do not know how to cater for it.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Should the menu exceed available screen space, the system will shrink the menu to fit, and provide scroll buttons at the top and bottom.

Comment: Can you provide that as a definitive "answer"? Perhaps with a suitable screenshot? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard menu implementation provides the functionality to automatically add scrollbars, should the number of entries exceed the menu's maximum height. By default a popup menu's height is set to 0, instructing the system to use the screen height as the menu's maximum height.

This works for a number of scenarios, and you don't have to do anything to get that behavior. It does fail, though, for multimonitor setups, where the height of the primary display is larger than the height of the display, where the application is displayed.

To work around this, you can set the respective popup menu's maximum height, whenever it is displayed. The appropriate place would be [CWnd::OnInitMenuPopup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k665199.aspx):

```
void CMainFrame::OnInitMenuPopup( CMenu* pPopupMenu, UINT nIndex, BOOL bSysMenu ) {

    CFrameWnd::OnInitMenuPopup( pPopupMenu, nIndex, bSysMenu );

    if ( !bSysMenu && ( nIndex == 3 ) ) {  // Apply appropriate filter
        MENUINFO mi = { 0 };
        mi.cbSize = sizeof( mi );
        mi.fMask = MIM_MAXHEIGHT;
        mi.cyMax = 150;                    // Pick an appropriate value
        pPopupMenu->SetMenuInfo( &mi );
    }
}
```

This callback is called, whenever a popup menu is about to be displayed. The height has been arbitrarily set to `150`. You can pick any value you see fit in your application (e.g. the minimum height of all displays, a value based on the height of the display, where the menu will be displayed, etc.).

Scrollbars are added automatically, as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Menu with scrollbars]